# Custom views filter on computed field

Tags: 8, views

I've built a custom field into the view which displays the menu name a node is assigned to, but I want to filter on the menu name. How can you filter on this computed field? The only examples I have found are for updating the SQL query to filter on existing values in the table.

Comment: `but I want to filter on the menu name. How can you filter on this computed field?` when you say computed field, are you referring to the [computed field](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field) module? Also, I don't get how this "computed field" contains a menu name and not a number...

Comment: Not using the computed field module. I've written a custom field that outputs the name of the menu that the node is assigned to. This is what I want to filter on

Answer (score 0):

It is to my knowledge not possible to add a filter to a view for a computed field. A possible workaround would be to use hook_views_pre_render() to remove  rows before Drupal renders the view.

Example code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_pre_render().
 */
function mymodule_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view) {
  if ($view->id() === 'my_view' && $view->current_display === 'page_1') {
    foreach ($view->result as $key => $value) {
      $menu_name = $value->_entity->get('menu_name')->value;
      if ($menu_name !== 'My Menu') {
        // Remove row from the view
        unset($view->result[$key]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```